# Segmentation fault during runtime of console code in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, runtime-error, runtime

I'm trying to make a simple console student details display system whereby there are 2 classes, class student(Base class) with member variables for name and registration number and class studentAthlete(Derived class) with sports type string.
The code compiles sucessfully but on runtime only asks for student details but does not display the details as would be expected when I call the identify() function.
On code blocks, the error might not show but on online compiles such as https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler it shows that there is a Segmentation fault in the code.
Please assist where necessary.

My code is exactly(in whole) as is below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**Base class**/
class student
{
protected:
    string studName, studRegNum;
public:
    student(string stdName, string regNo);
    /**To define friendly class that is
    Common to both classes**/
    friend void identify();
};
/**constructor for class student**/
student::student(string stdName, string regNo)
{
    studName = stdName;
    studRegNum = regNo;
}
/**Derived class**/
class studentAthlete : public student
{
private:
    string member_sport;
public:
    /**To create constructor for class studentAthlete within class**/
    studentAthlete(string student_sport):student(studName, studRegNum)
    {
        member_sport = student_sport;
    }
    /**To define friendly class that is
    Common to both classes**/
    friend void identify();
};

/**To display student information**/
void identify()
{

    studentAthlete sa(sa.member_sport);
    cout<<"Student Name: "<<sa.studName<<endl;
    cout<<"Student Registration Number: "<<sa.studRegNum<<endl;
    cout<<"Student Sport: "<<sa.member_sport<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    string StudentName, StudentRegistrationNo, StudentSport;
    /**To get & set student name from user**/
    cout<<"Enter student name: "<<endl;
    cin>>StudentName;

    /**To get & set Student Registration No from user**/
    cout<<"Enter Student Registration No: "<<endl;
    cin>>StudentRegistrationNo;

    /**To get & set Student Sport from user**/
    cout<<"Enter Student Sport: "<<endl;
    cin>>StudentSport;

    /**To pass student values to their respective constructors**/
    student st(StudentName,StudentRegistrationNo);
    studentAthlete sa(StudentSport);

    /**To display student information**/
    identify();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is this line supposed to mean `studentAthlete sa(sa.member_sport);` ?

Comment: This is not how derived-class inheritance works

Comment: @user463035818 because you cannot create an object with studentAthlete sa alone, I had to pass sa.member_sport to the constructor else without doing that I was getting the error "no matching function for call to 'studentAthlete::studentAthlete()' "

Comment: @Amadeus please help

Comment: do yourself a favour and dont write code merely to get rid of errors. Your code has several cases of undefined behaviour, actually I am severly puzzled how this can compile without warnings/errors

Comment: I agree with @user463035818. I think you need to spend some times on basic books

Comment: Quick rundown: Compiler error means code is syntactically incorrect and cannot be translated into executable code. Compiling code gives no guarantees that the code is logically correct and does something useful. This is like feeding [The Jabberwocky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky) into a English parser. It comes out correct, but quoth Alice, "Somehow it seems to fill my head with ideas--only I don't exactly know what they are! However, somebody killed something: that's clear, at any rate."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re passing uninitialised members to the `Student` constructor.
This will cause undefined behaviour.

You need to add name and number parameters to the athletes’  constructor and pass those to `Student`.

Comment: how about in the ```identify()  ```  ?function because thats where the error seems to be coming from