# Why can we use an object during its declaration?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration, undefined-behavior

I stumbled upon a line of code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695750/segmentation-fault-during-runtime-of-console-code-in-c?noredirect=1#comment98074164_55695750). It can be boiled down to

```
#include <iostream>
struct foo {
    int x;
    foo(int a) : x(a) {}
};

int main() {
    foo f(f.x);         // UB !!
    std::cout << f.x;
}
```

It compiles with a warning:

```
prog.cc:9:14: warning: 'f.foo::x' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     foo f(f.x);
```

Note that there is no such warning produced in the code from the question: https://wandbox.org/permlink/lNQWKWefobUtwD51

Now my question is two-fold. Sorry for putting two into one...

**Why can we use `f` before it is even declared?**

In `foo f(f.x);`, at which point is `f` declared? Isn't `(f.x)` part of the declaration? How is it possible that I can use the object as parameter to its constructor?

Next, I know that undefined behaviour is there for a reason, but I just cannot wrap my head around this case...

**Why does C++ need to allow writing `foo f(f.x);`? Why can / should it not be an error?**

I can imagine correct cases when the contructor takes a reference or a pointer and it is not used before `f` is fully constructed. However, `f.x` is passed by value and there is definitely no way `f.x` could have been initialized before it has been initialized.

Comment: There's a shorter mcve here. `void *p = &p;`

Comment: @StoryTeller hm shorter but less self-referential :P you can know the adress before you know what `p` is

Comment: From the link that you mention, i was trying to understand how this piece of code compile: `studentAthlete(string student_sport):student(studName, studRegNum)` It seems that is from the same reason of your question

Comment: @Amadeus It does compile, but I am puzzled why no warnings? (ie it even compiles with `-Werror`)

Comment: @user463035818 In either case, you need to `p` and `foo` to be declared before use. The `void*` example is pretty much the same and no more self-referencing.

Comment: I like `A a(a);`. Apparently so does the Fonze.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux `void *p = &p;` can make sense if you write it in two lines, while there is no way to get `foo f(f.x);` right. Anyhow, it was my fault to overcomplicate the example ;) The dupe is actually a different question, but I found what I was looking for